# Laravel Blueprint how to add options when creating the table

Tags: laravel-5, database-migration

I have a migration that I'm using to create a table.

My database is MySQL and I would like to add

```
CHECKSUM=1
```

to the create statement. How would I do this?

I don't see any way to pass database options when defining the `Schema::create` closure.

Laravel 5.4

Comment: You probably need to write the raw query.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using a DB::statement after the Schema::create.  It worked but I have to write the table name again in the raw query, and it is now a two step creation, a CREATE TABLE followed by an ALTER TABLE.